# Ayuda, necesito insertar un valor que viene de un putextra, adroid studio y mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

//  **ESTE ES  MI ACTIVITY  DESDE  INSERTAR  USUARIO**

**El  valor es un put extra, logusuario,me  muestra el  valor en pantalla pero no me  lo  registra en la base de  datos.**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_usuario);

    logusuario=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etingresadopor);
    Intent intmostrar= getIntent();
    mostrardelogin=intmostrar.getExtras().getString("UsuarioMostrar");
    logusuario.setText(mostrardelogin);


    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeAddUser);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusaurioAddUser);
    et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassAddUser);
    btnAddUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddUser);
    btnSalir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
    btnAddUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submitForm();
            et1.requestFocus();
            Limpiar();
        }
    });
```

}

//*******************************

```
        private void submitForm() {
        InsertarUser(et1.getText().toString(),
            et2.getText().toString(),
            et3.getText().toString(),
            muestraUser.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            logusuario.getText().toString()
            );
       }

     private void InsertarUser(final String Code,  final String User, 
    final String Pass,final String TipoUsuario,final String Usuario_ingreso) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "register";
    showLoadingDialog("Espere  insertando  datos ....");

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_ADD_USER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                hideLoadingDialog();
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String estado = jObj.getString("estado");

                if (estado.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                      Toast toast1= 
         Toast.makeText(addUsuario.this,"Inserción  correcta",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                    toast1.show();
                } else {
                    hideLoadingDialog();

                    Toast toast2= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se realizó la inserción  por que ya existe un Usuario con este código", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                    toast2.show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error al registrar: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideLoadingDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Code",Code);
            params.put("User", User);
            params.put("Pass",Pass);
            params.put("TipoUsuario", TipoUsuario);
            params.put("Usurio_ingreso",Usuario_ingreso);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
}



     public void showLoadingDialog(String texto) {
    try {
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        }
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage(texto);
        progressDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        progressDialog = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Es importante agregar como envias el valor a la Activity.  @Sofia

Comment: @Jorgesys, Hola  acabo de agregar de donde   obtengo el  valor  que  quiero insertar en   Usuarios, es desde  el Login  por que   mi  intención   es hacer  una  bitácora  y  recuperar  el  valor   de la  persona  que  ingresó  al sistema . agradezco tú ayuda.  Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por agregar la forma como lo envías, analizando tu código, el envió y la forma de mostrarlo en el `EditText` logusuario y posteriormente enviarlo al método `InsertarUser()` es correcto, el problema parece ser en el `HashMap` que creas para insertar los datos.

```
 @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        // Posting params to register url
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Code",Code);
        params.put("User", User);
        params.put("Pass",Pass);
        params.put("TipoUsuario", TipoUsuario);
        params.put("Usurio_ingreso",Usuario_ingreso); //*** Problema.
        return params;
    }
```

el nombre del parámetro seguramente debe ser "Usuario_ingreso".

Comment: solucionado error en   mi código php

Comment: y que error era? que debes recibir Usurio_ingreso en lugar de Usuario_ingreso ?

Comment: ese  era  un error, el  otro error era  en PHP, declaré  la variable para  llamarla   con el método  post y a la   hora  de insertarla  no la declaré.